# Can CreateJS be used for Mobile App Development?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, createjs

I am given a mobile app project and I'm looking at the technologies I can develop the app with. It is a mobile app to be used on tablets and smartphones. It will involve animations like fading in menus, changing opacities, transitions between pages, some minor sound playbacks... But it is not a game. **I need to be able to use HTML elements like tables or divs with auto-overflow.**

I started to create the app using HTML 5, CSS3, JavaScript and JQuery. But there are some problems I run into, like, animations being laggy, CSS3 not behaving the same, "touch" events behaving very differently, sound playback not being exactly the same among different browsers.

I recently saw that there are some JS libraries to make high performance animations, like CreateJS. My question is that should I use a library like this to create my mobile app? Or are such libraries only for game development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreateJS is not specially adapted for game development, there is no "game engine".
It just allows you to easily manipulate shapes, images, sounds in layers (Containers) like Flash.
Supports touch interactions in iOS, modern Android browsers and IE10.

So yes, you can use this library to create mobile app and you can combine it with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used createjs in mobile projects.  I would recommend reading the SoundJS [Mobile Safe tutorial (http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/)](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/).

Hope that helps.